# Delay render Android App with Cordova 5 and jQuery Mobile

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm developing an Android App using Cordova and jQuery Mobile.
Everything was fine, but, when I run the app into the smartphone its delay one or more second to render the jQuery.

First, at "Instant 0" is rendered only the "pure HTML". After, at "Instant 1", the jQuery Mobile components are rendered. The gap between Instants 0 and 1 is something around one sec.

The images below illustrate the Instants 0 and 1.

**Instant 0**

[image]

**Instant 1**

[image]

**The question is:** It is possible to eliminate this delay time?

**jQuery Mobile:** 1.4.3

**Android Platform:** 4.4.2

**IDE:** Eclipse Luna

**Smartphone:** Moto G 2 with Android KitKat 5.0.2

Source Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, 
        initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="pg-cadastro-aluno">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>HEADER</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sed consectetur nisl, ac mattis nunc. Integer a lacus volutpat, mattis felis eu, ornare eros. Vestibulum cursus leo nec imperdiet cursus. Aliquam id eleifend lacus, ac posuere arcu. In a elit vel arcu aliquam congue. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Duis quis erat et erat facilisis laoreet. Cras pharetra nunc vitae augue vulputate vulputate. Quisque nec ante sed purus vehicula laoreet eget at leo.          
            </p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>FOOTER</h1>
        </div>      
    </div>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"
        src="jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"
        src="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Important:** The instantes and source code presented here are only a very simple version of app to illustrate my situation.The real app is more complex, but the deley to render components is kept even in this simple version.

Comment: do you load some scripts from web in your html? do you launch javascript directly at startup?

Comment: Android 5 is Lolipop Android 4 is Kitkat. Did you upgrade your phone from 4 to 5. This may be the reason why your app is slow. What API version are you compiling your APP with. Make sure its the Latest API like 21 or 22. Also check the crosswalk project to use with cordova as its a faster browser than a webview -- https://crosswalk-project.org/

Comment: Hi @QuickFix thanks so much for the comment. All the scripts are loaded "locally". I didn't understand the question "do you launch javascript directly at startup?", but the whole of code are above.

Comment: Hi @Tasos, thanks so much for the comment. I did a several tests changing the API version in the Eclipse, 22, 21, 20, 19, even the 18 But the app remains rendering with the same delay... Lastly, I installed the app into other simple smartphone, a GP353 with Android 4.0.4 and it ran without the delay. I'm starting to think this issue is something between Cordova 5 and Android Lollipop. To be truth, there was a little delay in GP353, but the delay was loading app, and not rendering the JQM components. In GP353, for one instant the screen keeps white, and then, all JQM components appears rendered

Comment: I agree devices that came with Kitkat originally installed run faster.

Comment: We have other app developed before with Cordova 4.3.0. This app doesn't appear the delay to render the JQM components, even in Android Lollipop.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when running Cordova/JQuery Mobile a ruggedised Android that was very slow.

My solution, which worked great, was to load the JQuery Mobile scripts at the top of the HTML in the `<head>` section rather than at the bottom. Put all other scripts at the bottom.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Put JQuery Mobile scripts at top -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

    <!-- JQuery Mobile stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="pg-cadastro-aluno">
      <div data-role="header">
      <h1>HEADER</h1>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sed consectetur nisl, ac mattis nunc. Integer a lacus volutpat, mattis felis eu, ornare eros. Vestibulum cursus leo nec imperdiet cursus. Aliquam id eleifend lacus, ac posuere arcu. In a
          elit vel arcu aliquam congue. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Duis quis erat et erat facilisis laoreet. Cras pharetra nunc vitae augue vulputate vulputate. Quisque nec ante sed purus vehicula laoreet eget at leo.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>FOOTER</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Put all other scripts here at bottom -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

See this jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bckq9om8/